# Merging issue between array and string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, algorithm, merge

I have an array containing letters and colors.

```
const a = [
    {char: 'h', color: 'red'}, 
    {char: 'e', color: 'red'}, 
    {char: 'y', color: 'red'},
    {char: ' ', color: 'green'},
    {char: 't', color: 'red'}, 
    {char: 'h', color: 'red'}, 
    {char: 'e', color: 'red'}, 
    {char: 'r', color: 'red'}, 
    {char: 'e', color: 'red'}
];
```

I want to write a function that merges this with a string:

`const s = 'hey, howdy there';`

While preserving the original mapping of chars to colors. For instance, the chars that compose `hey` and `there` should all still be red and the  green, as originally painted in array a, while the new chars default to something arbitrary, say yellow and the old chars get deleted. So, the output of this function would give me something like:

```
res = [
    {char: 'h', color: 'red'}, 
    {char: 'e', color: 'red'}, 
    {char: 'y', color: 'red'},
    {char: ',', color: 'yellow'},
    {char: ' ', color: 'green'},
    {char: 'h', color: 'yellow'}, 
    {char: 'o', color: 'yellow'}, 
    {char: 'w', color: 'yellow'}, 
    {char: 'd', color: 'yellow'}, 
    {char: 'y', color: 'yellow'}, 
    {char: ' ', color: 'yellow'},
    {char: 't', color: 'red'}, 
    {char: 'h', color: 'red'}, 
    {char: 'e', color: 'red'}, 
    {char: 'r', color: 'red'}, 
    {char: 'e', color: 'red'}
];
```

One approach might be to extract the chars from `const a`, join them into a string and split on space, so you have an array of words. Repeat with string s. Loop over the new split array of string s until there is a mismatch between that and the original array a split. That would happen on the `,` char.

This is where I'm not sure how to proceed. In a simple case, where there is only two words, you can just keep the first word and replace everything else with the new words from the string s split. However, in the case that I provided, I'm adding values to the new string (i.e. `, howdy`) while preserving values of the old array (`there`).

I imagine that the algorithm that git uses to diff text would work here but I'm not sure exactly how to replicate it, or if it would even be efficient in this use case.

EDIT: 
I modified it a bit because I realized some of it was inconsistent.

Comment: I think you need to research how to determine the edit difference between two strings. That should tell you that `, howdy` was inserted, and you can mark that in yellow.

Comment: not sure i understand what you're going for.  the question calls the array `const a` a "mapping", but as an array, it's more than a mapping because it maintains order.  It also contains duplicate chars, like the 'e' in 'hey' and the the 'e's in 'there'.  The values for those keys are the same in your example, but can they sometimes differ?  A true mapping would look something like `{ h: "red", e: "red" ... }`  there would be no ordering and no duplicate keys.  The algorithm to handle this as input/output would be quite simple.  Is that what you want?

Comment: @Barmar the edit difference is what I was looking for but didnt have the vocabulary to describe. i did some research and the myer's diff algorithm is what i need. thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

https://jsfiddle.net/jdv9gz01/

```
function megaJoin (orig, newWord, index) {
var tmpArr = orig.slice();
    var newWordArray = newWord.split('').map((char)=>{return {char:char, color:'yellow'}});
  Array.prototype.splice.apply(tmpArr, [index,0].concat(newWordArray));
  return tmpArr;
}
```

I was unsure where the join should happen, so my function uses index to know where we should join.

If you don't know what newWord is, this function will get it. It's not perfect tho.

```
function getDifference(weirdArray, newString) {
    var tmps = [];
    for (var i = 0; i <= weirdArray.length; i++) {
        var word = a[i];
        if (word && word.char !== '' && i !== a.length) {
            tmps.push(word.char);
        } else {
            newString = newString.replace(tmps.join(''), '');
            tmps = [];
        }
    }
    return newString;
}
```

Comment: Would this work if you don't know what newThingy is beforehand? My problem is that I have two arbitrary strings to merge and want to preserve color information on the merge from the old to the new.

Comment: So, in megaJoin function, will newWord always be a string, or may it be an array similar to orig?

Comment: newWord will always be a string, but in the fiddle, you already manually picked out what was different about the two via the newThingy const. If I had that already and it was a matter of just mapping, then your answer would suffice, but the problem is that the function has to find what newThingy is, not me manually.

Comment: I made a quick and dirty fix to get it. https://jsfiddle.net/jdv9gz01/1/. `difference` will be equal to `newThingy` in my previous example.